# Wrong number of templet arguments

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap

Can anyone point the mistake here? I am using `pair<pair<int,int>,int>` as my key but I am getting this error:

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘int 
Solution::findMaxForm(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, int, int)’:
prog.cpp:33:24: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be at least 2)
     map<p<p<int,int>,int>,int> fma;
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define p pair
#define mp make_pair
class Solution {
public:
int oz(int i,int s,int a[][2],int m,int n,map<p<p<int,int>,int>,int> &fma){
    if(i>=s || (m+n)==0) return 0;
int ans;
if(fma.find(mp(mp(m,n),i)) !=fma.end()) return fma[mp(mp(m,n),i)];
ans =max(1+oz(i+1,s,a,m-a[i][0],n-a[i][1],fma),oz(i+1,s,a,m,n,fma));
fma[mp(mp(m,n),i)]=ans;
return ans;
}
int findMaxForm(vector<string>& strs, int m, int n) {
    int s=strs.size();
    int a[s][2];
     //some code
    map<p<p<int,int>,int>,int> fma;
    return oz(0,s,a,m,n,fma);
}
};
```

Comment: The first 4 lines should be completely removed and never used again.

Comment: Agreed with @super, but unfortunately it builds perfectly (g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0). What compiler are you using? Any additional flags?

Comment: Which 4 lines ? "#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define p pair
#define mp make_pair  "        these?

Comment: Compiles with gcc-10.1.0: https://wandbox.org/permlink/REdbAHX5kyjBkSrI